# Doing a loop on function parameters

Tags: jquery, loops, jvectormap

This is the current working code :

```
$.fn.vectorMap('addMap', 'world', {"width":950,"height":550,"paths":{
    id:{"path":data.id.path,"name":data.id.name},
    pg:{"path":data.pg.path,"name":data.pg.name},
    mx:{"path":data.mx.path,"name":data.mx.name},
    ee:{"path":data.ee.path,"name":data.ee.name},
    dz:{"path":data.dz.path,"name":data.dz.name},
    ma:{"path":data.ma.path,"name":data.ma.name},
    mr:{"path":data.mr.path,"name":data.mr.name},
    sn:{"path":data.sn.path,"name":data.sn.name},
    gm:{"path":data.gm.path,"name":data.gm.name},
    gw:{"path":data.gw.path,"name":data.gw.name},
    gn:{"path":data.gn.path,"name":data.gn.name},
    sl:{"path":data.sl.path,"name":data.sl.name},
    lr:{"path":data.lr.path,"name":data.lr.name},
    ci:{"path":data.ci.path,"name":data.ci.name},
    ml:{"path":data.ml.path,"name":data.ml.name},
    bf:{"path":data.bf.path,"name":data.bf.name},
    ne:{"path":data.ne.path,"name":data.ne.name},
    gh:{"path":data.gh.path,"name":data.gh.name},
    tg:{"path":data.tg.path,"name":data.tg.name},
    bj:{"path":data.bj.path,"name":data.bj.name},
    ng:{"path":data.ng.path,"name":data.ng.name},
    tn:{"path":data.tn.path,"name":data.tn.name},
    ly:{"path":data.ly.path,"name":data.ly.name},
    eg:{"path":data.eg.path,"name":data.eg.name},
    td:{"path":data.td.path,"name":data.td.name},
    sd:{"path":data.sd.path,"name":data.sd.name},
    cm:{"path":data.cm.path,"name":data.cm.name},
    er:{"path":data.er.path,"name":data.er.name},
    dj:{"path":data.dj.path,"name":data.dj.name},
    et:{"path":data.et.path,"name":data.et.name},
    so:{"path":data.so.path,"name":data.so.name},
    ye:{"path":data.ye.path,"name":data.ye.name},
    cf:{"path":data.cf.path,"name":data.cf.name},
    st:{"path":data.st.path,"name":data.st.name},
    gq:{"path":data.gq.path,"name":data.gq.name},
    ga:{"path":data.ga.path,"name":data.ga.name},
    cg:{"path":data.cg.path,"name":data.cg.name},
    ao:{"path":data.ao.path,"name":data.ao.name},
    cd:{"path":data.cd.path,"name":data.cd.name},
    rw:{"path":data.rw.path,"name":data.rw.name},
    bi:{"path":data.bi.path,"name":data.bi.name},
    ug:{"path":data.ug.path,"name":data.ug.name},
    ke:{"path":data.ke.path,"name":data.ke.name},
    tz:{"path":data.tz.path,"name":data.tz.name},
    zm:{"path":data.zm.path,"name":data.zm.name},
    mw:{"path":data.mw.path,"name":data.mw.name},
    mz:{"path":data.mz.path,"name":data.mz.name},
    zw:{"path":data.zw.path,"name":data.zw.name},
    na:{"path":data.na.path,"name":data.na.name},
    bw:{"path":data.bw.path,"name":data.bw.name},
    sz:{"path":data.sz.path,"name":data.sz.name},
    ls:{"path":data.ls.path,"name":data.ls.name},
    za:{"path":data.za.path,"name":data.za.name},
    gl:{"path":data.gl.path,"name":data.gl.name},
    au:{"path":data.au.path,"name":data.au.name},
    nz:{"path":data.nz.path,"name":data.nz.name},
    nc:{"path":data.nc.path,"name":data.nc.name},
    my:{"path":data.my.path,"name":data.my.name},
    bn:{"path":data.bn.path,"name":data.bn.name},
    tl:{"path":data.tl.path,"name":data.tl.name},
    sb:{"path":data.sb.path,"name":data.sb.name},
    vu:{"path":data.vu.path,"name":data.vu.name},
    fj:{"path":data.fj.path,"name":data.fj.name},
    ph:{"path":data.ph.path,"name":data.ph.name},
    cn:{"path":data.cn.path,"name":data.cn.name},
    tw:{"path":data.tw.path,"name":data.tw.name},
    jp:{"path":data.jp.path,"name":data.jp.name},
    ru:{"path":data.ru.path,"name":data.ru.name},
    us:{"path":data.us.path,"name":data.us.name},
    mu:{"path":data.mu.path,"name":data.mu.name},
    re:{"path":data.re.path,"name":data.re.name},
    mg:{"path":data.mg.path,"name":data.mg.name},
    km:{"path":data.km.path,"name":data.km.name},
    sc:{"path":data.sc.path,"name":data.sc.name},
    mv:{"path":data.mv.path,"name":data.mv.name},
    pt:{"path":data.pt.path,"name":data.pt.name},
    es:{"path":data.es.path,"name":data.es.name},
    cv:{"path":data.cv.path,"name":data.cv.name},
    pf:{"path":data.pf.path,"name":data.pf.name},
    kn:{"path":data.kn.path,"name":data.kn.name},
    ag:{"path":data.ag.path,"name":data.ag.name},
    dm:{"path":data.dm.path,"name":data.dm.name},
    lc:{"path":data.lc.path,"name":data.lc.name},
    bb:{"path":data.bb.path,"name":data.bb.name},
    gd:{"path":data.gd.path,"name":data.gd.name},
    tt:{"path":data.tt.path,"name":data.tt.name},
    do:{"path":data.do.path,"name":data.do.name},
    ht:{"path":data.ht.path,"name":data.ht.name},
    fk:{"path":data.fk.path,"name":data.fk.name},
    is:{"path":data.is.path,"name":data.is.name},
    no:{"path":data.no.path,"name":data.no.name},
    lk:{"path":data.lk.path,"name":data.lk.name},
    cu:{"path":data.cu.path,"name":data.cu.name},
    bs:{"path":data.bs.path,"name":data.bs.name},
    jm:{"path":data.jm.path,"name":data.jm.name},
    ec:{"path":data.ec.path,"name":data.ec.name},
    ca:{"path":data.ca.path,"name":data.ca.name},
    gt:{"path":data.gt.path,"name":data.gt.name},
    hn:{"path":data.hn.path,"name":data.hn.name},
    sv:{"path":data.sv.path,"name":data.sv.name},
    ni:{"path":data.ni.path,"name":data.ni.name},
    cr:{"path":data.cr.path,"name":data.cr.name},
    gr:{"path":data.gr.path,"name":data.gr.name}}
 });
```

As you can see, I am just listing all the elements into data. So, my question is : Can I do a loop on data to have exactly the same with only one row? Then how to do it because the elements are into a parameter of the vectorMap function.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create this data structure more simply, you could loop over the keys in `data` and build the required objects array, something like this:

```js
var options = {
  width: 950,
  height: 550,
  paths: {}
};
for (var key in data) {
  options.paths[key] = {
    path: data[key].path,
    name: data[key].name
  }
}
$.fn.vectorMap('addMap', 'world', options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.assign` and `Object.entries` to do this in one expression:

```
"paths": Object.assign(...Object.entries(data).map( ([k,v]) => ({ [k]: v }) ))
```

Note however that this will inject the whole `data.xx` objects, including any other properties they might have besides `path` and `name`. If this is undesired, then:

```
"paths": Object.assign(...Object.entries(data).map(
    ([k, {path,name}]) => ({ [k]: {path, name} }) 
))
```

Comment: Your solution works great. However, I find Rory solution better readable. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) NB: Yes, *functional programming* code style can be hard to read.